# MomentJS change text when certain condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

Currently I am working with momentJS and I want to change the text of an element when a certain condition is true.

To get a day in MomentJS you can just do `moment().day()` and the same for hours and minutes. The days reach from 1 (Monday) to 7 (Sunday).

I have a so called "cutoff" time for ordering items. For instance "Order before 8pm, delivered the next day" So in that case the cutoff time is 8pm.

The condition I want to have is, When it is day 5 (Friday) and it is past cutoff time (8pm). It needs to show the text "Order before Monday evening, delivered on Thursday". But say for instance it is Saturday 9am, it still needs to show that message. Only when It is past Monday 8pm it is supposed to show the default message again.

The code I wrote looks like the following:

```
 if(moment().day() > 5 && moment().hour() > cutoff.hour() && moment().minute() > cutoff.minute()) {
                tempCutOff = moment().set({'day': 1, 'hour': cutoffValues[0] - 1, 'minute': cutoffValues[1] - 1});
                tempTimeLeft = moment(tempCutOff.diff(moment()))

                $('.timerText').html("Order before " + tempCutOff.format('dddd') + "evening");
                if(tempTimeLeft.days() > 0) {
                    str = tempTimeLeft.days() + " days " + tempTimeLeft.hours() + " hours and " + timeLeft.minutes() + " minutes";
                } else {
                    str = timeLeft.hours() + " hours and " + timeLeft.minutes() + " minutes";
                }
                $("#orderCountdownTimer").html(str);
                tempCutOff.add(1, 'days')
                $('.timerTextExtra').html("delivered on " + tempCutOff.format('dddd'));
            }
```

EDIT::
Declarations

```
let cutoffValues = $('.cutoff_value').val().split(":");
let str = "";
let cutoff = moment().set({'day': moment().day(), 'hour': cutoffValues[0] - 1, 'minute': cutoffValues[1]})

let timeLeft = moment(cutoff.diff(moment()));
let tempCutOff;
let tempTimeLeft;
```

The problem with this if statement is that if it is Satuday 9am. This condition is false again. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: could you please show how you declare `cutoff`?

Comment: My apologies, I edited the question

Comment: You can't do an && with the cutoff minutes like that, because the next hour the minutes will reset to 0 again but you'll still be later than the cuttoff time. Edit: Oh, this is basically your question.

Comment: Yeah I know but how can I built the if statement so my condition stated above is true?

Comment: @Rainierlaan see my answer, maybe it's not the complete solution but it should get  you there.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to compare the whole datetime instead of checking each field seperatly.

First calculate the next cutoff time and if it's past friday set it to friday.

```
let cutoff = moment().set({'hour': cutoffValues[0] - 1, 'minute': cutoffValues[1]})
if ( moment().day() > 5 ) { cutoff.set({'day': 5}) }
```

Then compare if the current time is past the cutoff

```
if ( moment().isAfter(cutoff) {
  (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as you're using moment.js, you can simply check if a date is between two other dates, so let's assume you create a `cutOffStart` (which is Friday, 8pm) and a `cutOffEnd` (which is Monday, 8pm).
This should do the trick:

```
const current = moment();

const cutoffStart = moment();
cutoffStart.day('Friday').hour('8');

const cutoffEnd = moment();
cutoffEnd.day('Monday').hour('8');

if(current.isBetween(cutoffStart, cutoffEnd)){
 // display your text
}
```

you could still use moment.js `.diff` method to get day and hours difference between the two